# Is my textbook solution wrong or am I missing something?

Tags: numerical-methods

This is from my textbook:

> ***Example 2.16:*** Find a root of the equation $x \sin x + \cos x = 0$.
>
> We have
>   $$
>  f(x) = x \sin x + \cos x
>  \quad\text{and}\quad
>  f'(x) = x \cos x.
> $$
>   The iteration formula is, therefore,
>   $$
>  x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n \sin x_n + \cos x_n}{x_n \cos x_n}.
> $$
>   With $x_0 = \pi$, the successive iterates are given below:
>   $$
>  \begin{array}{cccc}
>   n &  x_n   &            f(x_n)           & x_{n+1} \\
>   \hline
>   0 & 3.1416 &           -1.0\phantom{000} & 2.8233 \\
>   1 & 2.8233 &           -0.0662           & 2.7986 \\
>   2 & 2.7986 &           -0.0006           & 2.7984 \\
>   3 & 2.7984 & \phantom{-}0.0\phantom{000} & 2.7984
>  \end{array}
> $$

My doubt here is that in last row of table where $x_n = 2.7984$ is $f(2.7984) \approx 1$, which is not near zero. So is this a misprint or am I missing something here? (This has happened to me in earlier questions in which I used the Newton-Raphson method.)

Comment: $f(2.7984)$ is pretty close to $0$. $\sin 2.7984 \approx 0.3365$, so $2.7984\cdot \sin 2.7984 \approx 0.94165$, and $\cos 2.7984 \approx -0.941685$. How did you calculate? Pocket calculator? That may have used degree mode.

Comment: @DanielFischer My calculator is showing something else. It always screws me up in Newton Raphson

Comment: I guess your calculator is set to degree mode. Set it to radians mode.

Comment: @DanielFischer How to do ? I am using CASIO fx 991ES Plus

Comment: I don't know that one. If there is no button with `DEG` or `DRG` (degrees, radians, grad/gon), look in the user manual.

Comment: @DanielFischer There is DRG written on top of a button adjacent to "="

Comment: Then pressing `2nd` + `=` (maybe on Casio calculators it's called `Shift` rather than `2nd`, or it has a colour code, whatever) should cycle you through the modes. Typically, the mode is indicated in the display, there should be a small `Rad` somewhere in the display after switching mode.

Comment: @DanielFischer BINGO! Your guess was right. Please post an answer so that i like it and accept it. Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculators usually are by default in "degree mode", that is, they interpret arguments to trigonometric functions as given in degrees. In mathematical contexts, the default is that the arguments to trigonometric functions are given in radians. Using the wrong mode leads to wrong results, since e.g. $\pi°$ is a small angle whose cosine is close to $1$, while $\pi$ is a straight angle with $\cos \pi = -1$.

Setting the calculator to radians mode avoids the discrepancy.